# Align picture to text

Tags: spacing, floats, minipage

I need to put a university's logo in a text and I'm not getting it aligned when I use the `\newtheorem` command. I tried to use the `\hspace` command but it is not working. For the text without Theorem, Propositions, ... the figure is aligned.
My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pctex32]{graphics}
\usepackage{ amsmath,  amsfonts}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{minipage}{0\linewidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{logoUTFPR}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Roteiro de Atividades\\
        Professor Mateus Eduardo Salomão}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
 
\begin{theorem}[Teorema de]
Seja $f$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This code  is generating the following:
[image]

I would like it to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
In the first try I misunderstood your problem. Now is corrected. All what you need is insert `noindent before first` minipage `and use`raggedright` for placement of figure inside it.

BTWE; you should  never ever enclose floats  `figure` (or `table`) inside minipage or similar box.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[pctex32]{graphics}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{logoUTFPR}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
\centering
\textbf{Roteiro de Atividades\\
        Professor Mateus Eduardo Salomão}
\end{minipage}

\begin{theorem}[Teorema de]
Seja $f$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But his figure was not aligned with the text below, which I would like to do.

Comment: @Croos, sorry, how should be aligned? Should bot start at left border?

Comment: I edited and added in the text how this alignment is. I put a new image.

Comment: @Croos, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Zarko